# Apple Pay - Payment backend server - iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, payment, applepay, passkit

I have been reading the Apple developer documentation website about Apple Pay and have been going through other tutorials online about how to integrate Apple Pay into your iOS apps.

All of the sites I have been on indicate that you need a backend server/service that can handle the payment. Does anyone know if there is a way around this. Personally I just Apple to handle the payments in my app. Why do I have to have a backend as well?? I thought the whole point of Apple Pay is that it takes care of the payment....

I will be selling services to the user in my app and not physical products, so its not like I need to handle shipping or anything like that.

There are delegate methods of course which tell you if the payment was a success or not. That seems good enough for me. Can't I just use them?

The problem is that if you use a backend, you need to use a service like Stripe which then takes about 2.9% of each transaction via a fee.... just is a lot on a big scale (or even a small scale to be honest).

Thanks for your time, Dan.

Comment: if you really need backend, create some at ur end using php.. its easy...

Comment: You dont have to write a server side yourself. Use PayumServer - https://github.com/Payum/PayumServer. Just install it and configure via web client.

Answer (score 2):

Apple doesn't process the payment with the card issuer (Visa, MasterCard, etc), all they are doing is telling you that the attempt to pay is authorized by the user (i.e. a proper fingerprint has been received on the touchID sensor). They have no idea if the card will actually charge properly. That's where you need a payment processor like Stripe. While I'm sure it's technically possible to be your own credit card processor, I wouldn't even bother. You'd be going down an extremely long and complicated road. At the end of the day 2.9% is well worth it if you want to accept credit cards.